# how can i map panning bounds in an area using wrld.js

Tags: javascript, maps

i want this functionality

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/restrict-bounds/

in wrld javascript sdk

https://www.wrld3d.com/wrld.js/latest/docs/examples/

wrld javascript sdk is using leaflets but it does not support some of the functions like lock zoom level and restrict panning into certain area.

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 0
});
```

this does not supported in wrld.js

so i achieve this by following code

```
function updatePopup() {

    var zoom = map.getZoom();
    var center = map.getCenter();

    if(zoom < 15){
        map.setView(center, 15, {
        animate: false
    });
    }
  }

  map.on("update", updatePopup);
```

but i am still not able to set panning please help

https://jsfiddle.net/mrt2yxpu/

this is working example.